# Creating a sort key in DynamoDB on nested attributs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

My document in DyanamoDB follows the following structure

```
{
    "id": "<<GUID>>",
    "ts": <<unix_epoch>>
    "audit": {
        "lastUpdatedOn": <<unix_epoch>>
    }
}
```

I wan't to create a secondary GSI on this table with `id` as the PK and the `audit.lastUpdatedOn` as the SK.

Can I use a nested property as a sort key? (I tried to do it, but it didn't behave the way i wanted it to behave)

Comment: How did it behave?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not allowed. DynamodBb permits only `string`, `number` and `binary` scalar types as keys:

> [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) Each primary key attribute must be a scalar (meaning that it can hold only a single value). The only data types allowed for primary key attributes are string, number, or binary. There are no such restrictions for other, non-key attributes.

Comment: The audit.lastUpdatedOn attribute is a scalar, even though this is a nested attribute. The issue is that indexes, including [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html), only support top-level attributes.